# Can't start uWSGI server without virtualenv (ImportError)

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, wsgi, uwsgi

I'm running django+nginx+uwsgi. For some reason I cannot start uWSGI without setting home option, pointing to virtual environment. Whenever I start uWSGI without it, it says that it cannot find module django.core.wsgi, like if python path was empty (but django 1.4 is installed system-wide).

How can i fix it?

Comment: There's nothing wrong. You need to use the `home` option to specify the virtual environnent in which django is installed. Otherwise, uwsgi will be operating at a system wide level, where django isn't installed. Look at the [uwsgi example](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnv).

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony if you look at my question closely, you can actually see, that i mentioned that django is installed "system-wide".

Comment: I'll edit it to make it more clear

Comment: a uwsgi start up log would be helpful

Comment: Could you attach pdb to it and print sys.path?

Comment: @DataGreed I think you fix your problem so can you post answer and set question as resolved.

Comment: Hi, no I just gave it up and set a virtual env.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since I hit my head on this problem too, let's write an answer for all. :)
The problem is that, when starting in emperor mode (system wide), the uwsgi master process can't (or won't) load the correct environ for python (PYTHONPATH).
Using virtualenv you specify the environ.
Without it you need to set the `pythonpath` variable, even multiple times pointing to the system-wide python paths.

Just as an example, for my system it's:

```
pythonpath = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
pythonpath = /usr/lib/python2.7
```

(using the ini syntax)

Comment: I encounter this error in MacOS system but not in centos6 with same configuration file. Fix it after add `virtualenv` in configuration file. Can you explain this situration?  The running command is `/path_to_venv/bin/uwsgi -y uwsgi.conf`

Comment: @SiminJie sorry i don't use MacOS. And I wouldn't use it as a server.

Comment: For me setting the `virtualenv` setting is not enough and I need to set the `pythonpath` for uwsgi to find flask etc. Is that expected or what could be the reason?